# web deploy deploymentskiprule

Tags: c#, webdeploy

I'm trying to use the web deploy api in c#, i've got most things covered except for one thing I'm trying to exclude the root web.config file and I can't find the right way to do it.

Currently I've got this code:

```
        var syncOptions = new DeploymentSyncOptions { DeleteDestination = false };
        syncOptions.Rules.Add(new DeploymentSkipRule("DontUpdateRootConfig", "update", "", "Web.config", ""));
```

But this ignores all web.config files, it should only ignore the root web.config file.

The code below doesn't work. It simply transfers all config files including the root web.config.

```
        var syncOptions = new DeploymentSyncOptions { DeleteDestination = false };
        syncOptions.Rules.Add(new DeploymentSkipRule("DontUpdateRootConfig", "update", "", "\\Web.config", ""));
```

How can I ignore only the root web.config file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the "absolutepath" argument is a regular expression.

I fixed my issue this way

```
var siteAndAppName = "example.com";
var syncOptions = new DeploymentSyncOptions { DeleteDestination = false };
syncOptions.Rules.Add(new DeploymentSkipRule("DontUpdateRootConfig", "update", "", siteAndAppName + "\\\\Web.config", ""));
```